# chmod g+w+s on the directory without changing umask (Linux)?

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, file-sharing

I'd like to make new files, created in a directory, writable by others in the same Posix group without using ACLs. Not sure this is possible.

The way I've accomplished this in the past was to change every users `umask` to `0002` and then `chmod g+w+s` on the directory containing the shared files (output edited for brevity):

```
$ mkdir shared ## create a shared location
$ ls -lart
drwxr-xr-x  2 user234 sysadmin 4096 Mar  1 10:02 shared

$ groups ## must be member of group to share with
sysadmin webdevel sysconfig

$ chmod g+w+s shared ## set new files for group write/:sysconfig ownership
$ chown :sysconfig shared
$ ls -lart
drwxrwsr-x  2 user234 sysconfig 4096 Mar  1 10:02 shared

$ touch shared/file1 ## need umask for group write?
$ ls -lart shared/file1 
-rw-r--r-- 1 user234 sysconfig 0 Mar  1 10:03 shared/file1

$ umask
0022          ## no group write bits

$ umask 0002  ## set umask to add group write by default

$ touch shared/file2 ## ok fine                                                                                                
$ ls -lart shared/file2
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user234 sysconfig 0 Mar  1 10:03 shared/file2

$ touch ~/tps_reports  ## files created in home are GW now as well
$ ls -lart ~/tps_reports
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user234 sysadmin 0 Mar  1 10:08 /home/user234/tps_reports
```

The problem with changing the `umask` is when users create files elsewhre (for instance in their home directories where group read/write isn't typically wanted) these also have group-write by default since `umask` affects files across the local filesystems. Are ACLs the only way to fix this?

Comment: Can you change your comments from `<<` to a `#` character? The `<<` is a a bash IO redirection operator.

Comment: How are the files being created? In an interactive shell session or programmatically?

Comment: (arrows changed, thanks) Interactive shell logins